# How can I prove that a sequence such that every converging subsequence coverges to the same limit, converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, limsup-and-liminf, weak-convergence

I want to claim that if $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ is a sequence, and there is $a$ such that if $(x_{n_k})$ converges, so $\lim x_{n_k} = a$ (**it means that all converging subsequences have the same limit**), then $(x_n)$ converges. (I don't really mind sequence of what.. could be numbers, could be a sequence in any Hilbert space).

Is my proposition even right?

Assume that a converging subsequence *exists*, if it helps. I think it should.

My intuition is **YES**, using some how that $\liminf =\limsup$ (**Why is that right exactly? as explicitly as you could**).

Does it also hold for *weak* convergence?

Thanks!

**Added: assume it's bounded. I understood it is false if not bounded**

Comment: Looks incorrect: how about $a_n = (-1)^n$

Comment: Not if the sequence is unbounded.

Comment: @SimonS: it is not a good counterexample because i asked that all converging subsequences converges **to the same limit**.

Comment: @DavidMitra: could you explain how the boundness is used/required?

Comment: What about a sequence with no convergent subsequence. Then vacuously, all convergent subsequences converge to the same limit, but the sequence does not converge.

Comment: Ok, what you just wrote wasn't clear in your original question. Perhaps make an edit there.

Comment: @Nishant: That's why I said you could assume that a convering subsequence exists

Comment: take the sequence $x_{2n} = n$ and $x_{2n+1} = 0$ then each converging subsequence goes to $0$ but the seuqence diverges

Comment: For example the sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n=n$ satisfies your hypothesis with $a=123833$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:
$$
a_n = 
\begin{cases}
0, & n \mbox{ even }\\
n, & n \mbox{ odd }
\end{cases}
$$

However, as David Mitra points out, if you require boundedness, then the result should hold.

---

Let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers such that every convergent subsequence converges to the same number $a$. Suppose toward contradiction it does not converge to $a$. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $|a_n - a|>\epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$.

Index these as $b_k$. This is a bounded sequence of real numbers, hence has a convergent subsequence. By construction, this convergent subsequence cannot converge to $a$. However, it is a subsequence of $a_n$. Contradiction.

(The proof is the same for such sequences in any compact metric space.)

Comment: Thanks. could you prove it while using boundeness?

Comment: @Functional_Analysis Yep!